# Is an ORM appropriate for a read-only application?

Tags: database, orm

I am tasked with creating a reporting application working off a internal database.

The database is populated by some other tools, and the aim of the application is basically to read from the DB, and display some charts.

To that end, the application will only ever connect with a read-only account.

I have been reading about ORM, especially Entity Framework, but is seems to be very focused of making DB structure, and DB updating easier.

Since the only purpose of the app is reading from the DB, will I gain anything from using an ORM such as Entity Framework or Linq2SQL, or should I stick with good-ol' SqlCommands?

Answer (score 0):

If you need some kind of dashboard to display aggregated data from a SQL Server database I would recommend [Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports). You would need a SQL Server license on the machine that serves the site.

You can of course create a dashboard from scratch using Entity Framework, but hey, why reinvent the wheel?